# Android SQLite batch insertion

Tags: android, database

I need to insert a lot of rows in the database at a time and I'm seeking for the most efficient way to do it. I have seen code like this:

```
db.beginTransaction();
for (ModelObject object : modelObjectsCollection){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    ... // fill values variable with values from object
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    values.clear();
}
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
```

In this case all inserts are accomplished as a single operation which takes less time. Will it still work as a single operation if I incapsulate insertion of a single row into a method like this:

```
public void insertAllRows(){
    db.beginTransaction();
    for (ModelObject object : modelObjectsCollection){
        insertSingleRow(object);
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}

public void insertSingleRow(ModelObject object){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    ... // fill values variable with values from object
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}
```

Will it be accomplished in a single transaction as well?
Besides, I do not understand: is it correct that if we do not call

```
db.beginTransaction(); ... db.setTransactionSuccessful();
```

explicitly, but only call db.insert(), beginTransaction()-setTransactionSuccessful() methods are invoked inside insert(). In contrary, if we invoke insert() between invokations of beginTransaction()-setTransactionSuccessful(), the latter 2 methods aren't invoked inside insert()?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute queries without transactions at all. And there are no need in transaction for single query at all.
Also you need to call db.endTransaction(); after db.setTransactionSuccessful() for commiting it.

upd: you can find more about common transaction use here http://www.4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-fgl-manual-html/User/Transactions.html for example.

Comment: My query is not single: I invoke insertSingleRow several times within a loop. By the way, I have already tested it: with no beginTransaction-endTransaction my inserts are completed in 1400~millisec and in 235millisec otherwise. So begin-end transaction means productivity boost.

Comment: Yes. Transaction use daramatically increase perfomance and also make batch of operations "atomic". But for single queries there are no need to use it.